# Need help in getting desired result through SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, subquery, max

I'm trying to find an year when most of the 'Mystery' genre movies are produced and count of the movies. As per the table sample data, the answer should be 2001 and 2.

Below is the code to create the tables with values

```
CREATE TABLE movie$
(
    mov_id int NOT NULL,
    mov_title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    mov_year int
);

INSERT INTO movie$ (mov_id, mov_title, mov_year)
VALUES 
(1001,'movie1', 2001),
(1002,'movie2', 2001),
(1003,'movie3', 2001),
(1004,'movie4', 2002),
(1005,'movie5', 2003);

CREATE TABLE movie_genres$
(
    mov_id int NOT NULL,
    gen_id int
); 
  
INSERT INTO movie_genres$ (mov_id, gen_id)
VALUES
(1001, 1),
(1002, 1),
(1003, 2),
(1004, 3),
(1005, 4);


CREATE TABLE Genres$
(
    gen_id int NOT NULL,
    gen_title varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Genres$ (gen_id , gen_title)
VALUES 
(1, 'Mystery'),
(2, 'Adventure'),
(3, 'Thriller'),
(4, 'Action');
```

Below is the query I'm trying to execute

```
SELECT 
    movie.mov_year, COUNT(movie.mov_year) AS 'total_movies'
FROM
    movie$ movie 
JOIN 
    movie_genres$ m_genres ON m_genres.mov_id = movie.mov_id
JOIN 
    genres$ genres ON genres.gen_id = m_genres.gen_id
                   AND genres.gen_title LIKE '%mystery%'
GROUP BY 
    movie.mov_year
HAVING 
    movie.mov_year IN (SELECT movie.mov_year mov_yr 
                       FROM movie$ m 
                       WHERE COUNT([mov_year]) = (SELECT MAX(movie_count) maxcount 
                                                  FROM 
                                                      (SELECT COUNT([dbo].[movie$].[mov_year]) movie_count 
                                                       FROM [dbo].[movie$] 
                                                       GROUP BY movie$.mov_year)))
```

I'm not getting where did I miss while putting an alias as it's showing me error at last bracket and also  it's not taking value of movie_count alias in MAX function.

[image]

Please guide.

Comment: Do your table names really end in `$`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I'll update them, requesting you to let me know your suggestions on the issue I' facing.

Comment: You said you solved that in your last question? Your alias goes between your last 2 brackets, if you lay it out better (rather than inline it) it becomes obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CTE` with `Row_Number()` to make this simple.

```
WITH MysteryMovies AS (
SELECT 
    movie.mov_year, COUNT(movie.mov_year) AS 'total_movies'
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(movie.mov_year) DESC ) AS rowId
FROM
    movie movie 
JOIN 
    movie_genres m_genres ON m_genres.mov_id = movie.mov_id
JOIN 
    genres genres ON genres.gen_id = m_genres.gen_id
                   AND genres.gen_title LIKE '%mystery%'
GROUP BY 
    movie.mov_year
)
SELECT mov_year
      ,total_movies  
FROM MysteryMovies 
WHERE rowId = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ef3c5284b73d48e8498c12dbddf8fb1)

Answer (score 1):

You write a very bad query.

Here is problem that I founded:

1. When using `COUNT()`, use `HAVING` for condition
2. Use alias for subqueries
3. **Check table names!!!**

```sql
SELECT
    movie.mov_year, COUNT(movie.mov_year) AS 'total_movies'
FROM 
    movie$ movie 
JOIN 
    movie_geners$ m_geners ON m_geners.mov_id = movie.mov_id
JOIN 
    geners$ geners ON geners.gen_id = m_geners.gen_id
                   AND geners.gen_title LIKE '%mystery%'
GROUP BY 
    movie.mov_year
HAVING 
    movie.mov_year IN
       (SELECT 
            mov_year mov_yr 
        FROM 
            movie$ m 
        GROUP BY 
            mov_year
        HAVING 
            COUNT([mov_year]) = 
               (SELECT 
                    MAX(a.movie_count) maxcount 
                FROM 
                   (SELECT 
                        COUNT([dbo].[movie$].[mov_year]) movie_count 
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[movie$] 
                    GROUP BY 
                        movie$.mov_year
                    ) AS a
               ) 
        )
```

Here, on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e88a480f9c5c8d66761cd402141255c), you can check how it works now.